# laravel trans('app.name') not working on js file

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

i created a translation web page, but my trans() function on working on php page.
In my blade page, i included some js file, when i try to print it on js file, it doesn't work at all.

My php blade

```
<script src="{{asset('public/assets/js/my.js')}}"></script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        My.init(); 
    });
```

In My.js

```
var FormElements = function() {"use strict";
    var myfunction = function(){ 
         var test = "{{trans('app.name')}}";
         console.log(test);
    }
    return {
        //main function to initiate template pages
        init: function() {
            myfunction();
        }
    };
}();
```

The output result is

> {{trans('app.name')}}

Should be

> Firstname

Can someone guide me, appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use laravel blade syntax inside javascript files. They will just be treated as a string. You have to pass the value to your method inside js file from the view or write the js code in the view. Try this in your blade view

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("{{ trans('app.name') }}");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this is working on my blade, but is not working on js file.

Comment: @php_dvp i've clearly mentioned that blade syntax won't work in js files. Just like php code won't run in js files.

Comment: i manage to fix it with passing value from blade to js file function.